# How to deal with spaces in a HTML/JavaScript class name

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am having problems getting data from a element using Selenium with the line:

```
bets = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sgl-ParticipantFixtureLink gl-Market_General-cn1 ')
```

I can get the data by using XPath, but getting all the values since they have the same class name would be more efficient.

Since I am pretty new to HTML, Python, JavaScript etc, I was wondering if need to change the class name, using:

```
"_" or "-"
```

to fill up the blank spaces in the class name?

```
bets = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sgl-ParticipantFixtureLink-gl-Market_General-cn1-')
```

or

```
bets = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sgl-ParticipantFixtureLink_gl-Market_General-cn1_')
```

It does not seem to return any value, but neither does it return null.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by this - "I can get the data by using XPath, but getting all the values since they have the same class name would be more efficient."

Comment: Since you don't seem to be aware, when an element has spaces in the `class` attribute, that means it has multiple classes.

Comment: Using XPath I only get 1 value. But if I was to get all the values with 1 function that would be more efficient, wouldn't it? Because all the values I want to get has the same "class name". @itronic1990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an element has spaces in the `class` attribute, that means it has multiple classes, so you'll need to handle that another way.

One option is with CSS selectors.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#locate-elements-by

```css
bets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sgl-ParticipantFixtureLink.gl-Market_General-cn1')
```

Start with a period (`.`) and have a period between each subsequent class (nothing at the end)

This will return a list containing all in elements with both of those classes

For example, if you wanted to convert this to a list of text, you would do this:

```py
# after the code above
texts = [bet.text for bet in bets]
```

Comment: Now I can find all the ```elements```, but can't get the value from them which is a number, between the ```"::before" and  "::after"```. I tried using .text but get ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'```.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Samathingamajig in case of multiple class names the simplest way to locate the element(s) is to use `css_selector`.
If there are several elements matching that locator you can iterate through the list of elements and get text from each one of them. Like this:

```
bets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sgl-ParticipantFixtureLink.gl-Market_General-cn1')
for bet in bets:
    text = bet.text
    print(text)
```